# Lack of SubVI needed to create an executable file in LabVIEW

Tags: vi, labview

I have created a VI in LabVIEW to capture an image and it works perfectly. But when I want to make an executable file from it, error 1003 appears when I'm clicking "source files". Probably the reason is that I don't have a SubVI called "AB_Source_RESTfulVI_configuration_dialog.vi" (that why the arrow in the "AB_UI_Page_Source_Files.vi" is broken).

Do you have any ideas why I don't have it on my computer? How can I fix it? Probably I should add that I have only a evaluation of LabVIEW, not a full version, but I've read and my mates checked that it's possible to make an .exe in evaluation mode.

Answer (score 3):

Simply you are not allowed to use additional features in executable when LabVIEW is in evaluation mode.

- Application Builder cannot use any "Additional Exclusions."
  http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/862567530005F09C8625675F00711756